# Screenshot Folder

Tags: macos

For some reason lately, whenever I take a screenshot, it will show up in the desktop folder for a second, and then disappear and I cannot find them. Does anyone know where they go?

Comment: In Terminal, what is the output of: `defaults read com.apple.screencapture`

Comment: Do you have any application installed which automatically processes desktop files?

Answer (score 2):

This is the procedure you need to follow to change your screenshot default's location.

Step 1: Open Terminal

Step 2: Type the following command: `defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop`, if you want to save the screenshots in the Desktop.

Step 3: Press enter(return key).

Step 4: Paste this command to save changes and see immediate effect: `killall SystemUIServer` and press return again.

Comment: The default location for screen shots is ~/Desktop and does not need to be defined in the com.apple.screencapture.plist file, which doesn't even exist by default. If the default location has been modified, then the proper command is `defaults delete com.apple.screencapture location` since it doesn't exist by default to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I would disconnect from any network in case you have iCloud syncing your desktop. Then perhaps log out and/or restart once you are disconnected and then re-test.

Missing files can be a sign of corruption, so you might check that your backup is current and then see about following the diagnosis steps to boot to recovery mode and check your drive catalog for errors or hardware failure:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314